# PouchDB designing for forwards compatibility

Tags: pouchdb

I am starting out with PouchDB and looking for a solution which will allow me to change my schema in future without major pain, so I don't have to worry now if I have thought of everything. I'm seeking to plan for the case where I might need to change to a structure which I didn't predict (example: Let's say I start with the concept of a single "wish list" but later support multiple named lists instead).

The high level idea I have is to have some internally-meaningful "schema version" that is saved into every PouchDB instance. Then my client side JS could read that in, and if there is a data migration necessary, it can perform that before continuing. Are there any "best practice" ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a plugin called [pouchdb-migrate](https://github.com/eHealthAfrica/pouchdb-migrate) that you can use to accomplish this. Keeping an integer version is fine; you can also use "duck versioning" (e.g. "I'm adding a `lastName` field in v2, so if there's no `lastName`, then the document must be v1").

Comment: Perfect timing! I see it was just released.

Comment: BTW would you consider that this "approach" (i.e. making the assumption I won't get schemas right first time, that I'll need to break compatibility at some point, and planning for it) is OK?